# Can't set element.style.properties in JS inside Lightning Locker

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

Minimal example under Lightning Locker:

StyleTest.app:

```
<aura:application >
    <p id="special">Look at me! I am so very special!</p>
    <ui:button label="Element.style.color = 'red'" press="{!c.handle1}" />
    <ui:button label="Element.style.setProperty('color', 'green')" press="{!c.handle2}" />
</aura:application>
```

StyleTestController.js:

```
({
    handle1 : function(c,e,h) {
        document.getElementById('special').style.color = 'red';
    },
    handle2 : function(c,e,h) {
        document.getElementById('special').style.setProperty('color', 'green');
    }
})
```

On API 37 with Lightning Locker enabled, both buttons try to set the same style property but only the second one succeeds. The first one silently fails. Now I realize it is not in general great practice to set inline styles using JavaScript when we can use classes instead, a lot of great plugins use these properties to dynamically style elements. For example the "qTip2" jQuery plugin runs into this issue: It is able to add classes and HTML attributes to the elements I select, but it is not successful at adding inline styles.

Given that setting .style.property fails but .style.setProperty() succeeds, can I gather that this is not intended behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue in the queue - both syntaxes should be supported - will be fixed in Summer'16 but I am not sure exactly when yet.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I already have a ticket open for this one so if there is a bug# I can attach to it that'd be great.

Comment: Case number 13993271 was opened last week for this.

Comment: Perfect - the bug is W-3193414

Comment: OK, added. My ticket was originally about qTip2 not working but clearly this issue is **at least** one root cause. When it is resolved I can go back and try various libraries again and report if any still don't work.

Comment: Hi Doug, as of today I can confirm this is now working in my sandbox. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Doug, looking at the issues page here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYWPQA4 I see that officially it hasn't been fixed yet although it looks like the fix is working on my end. It looks like other users on this forum are not seeing the fix live yet. Can you clarify?